# Expand Row of Table on Click and draw D3 charts inside

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to create a Table in which a row expands on click and two D3 charts are drawn inside the new expanded row.

**My logic for Expand Row:-**

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="item in nodeSummary">
    <td>
      <button ng-if="item.expanded" ng-click="tableRowExpand($index,false)">-</button>
      <button ng-if="!item.expanded" ng-click="tableRowExpand($index,true)">+</button>
    </td>
    <td>{{item.a}}</td>
    <td>{{item.b}}</td>
    <td>{{item.c}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="item.expanded" ng-repeat-end>
    <td colspan="4" style="height:100px;width:100%;">
      <div id="expanded-tablerow-container" style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:auto;" >
        <div id="expanded-tablerow-circleProgress" style="height:100%;width:20%;float:left;">Here</div>
        <div id="expanded-tablerow-barchart" style="height:100%;width:80%;float:left;">Here</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

So using `ng-repeat-start/end`, and `onClick` of button the particular row is expanded/shrinked.

**tableRowExpand function:-**

```
$scope.tableRowExpand =  function(index, value){

  $scope.nodeSummary[index].expanded = value;

  if (value){
    drawCircularProgressBar(d3.select("#expanded-tablerow-circleProgress"),0.8);
    drawHorizontalBar("#expanded-tablerow-barchart",data);
  }

};
```

So on checking `value` is `true` I am calling methods to draw d3 chart and bar. But they are not drawing.

**My Problems:-**

1. Well, I looked into the problem and it seems the problem is calling these method before the changes to the document is done, How I know this? Well, suppose if there are two rows, then on expanding 1st row, nothing is drawn but on then clicking the 2nd row, bar and chart is drawn on 1st row's expanded space. Am I able to make myself clear? So how to fix this problem?
2. Multiple rows can remain expanded at a time. I may have 100s of rows, and the d3 drawing is done based on data of each row which will vary, so each row will have unique d3 drawing on its expanded view. But as the drawing is done by passing the divs, which for all expanded rows will be same, won't this kill the uniqueness, saying same drawing on all expanded view?. In a way, how can I have unique drawing for each row?

Hope I was able to make myself clear. Please help me resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was finally able to solve it. Lets go for it.

**Problem 1)**

Yeah I was right :) The problem is that the document was not fullt loaded, I solved adding a simple check code,

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    //calling the d3 draw code here
    });
```

**Problem 2)**

I don't know if this is the most efficient way, if someone want to input, please do, but I did this.

```
var newCircleProgressId = 'expanded-tablerow-circleProgress' + index;
var newHoizontalBarId = 'expanded-tablerow-barchart' + index;
document.getElementById("expanded-tablerow-circleProgress").setAttribute('id',newCircleProgressId);
document.getElementById("expanded-tablerow-barchart").setAttribute('id', newHoizontalBarId);
```

i.e. dynamically altering the ID of the div inside the **tableRowExpand** function and passing this new ID along with row unique(extracted using index) to draw d3 functions.